# python 3.5 ubuntu Deep neural Networks syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run this code in Python version 3.5 in ubuntu using keras and tensorflow api in backend .But it shows syntax error in line 13.This is code taken from the link https://github.com/JostineHo/mememoji/tree/master/src.According to me there is no syntax error in the code.

```
enter code here
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.mo`enter code here`dels import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from log import save_model, save_config, save_result
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

def describe(X_shape, y_shape, batch_size, dropout, nb_epoch, conv_arch, dense):
    print ' X_train shape: ', X_shape # (n_sample, 1, 48, 48)
    print ' y_train shape: ', y_shape # (n_sample, n_categories)
    print '      img size: ', X_shape[2], X_shape[3]
    print '    batch size: ', batch_size
    print '      nb_epoch: ', nb_epoch
    print '       dropout: ', dropout
    print 'conv architect: ', conv_arch
    print 'neural network: ', dense

def logging(model, starttime, batch_size, nb_epoch, conv_arch,dense, dropout,
            X_shape, y_shape, train_acc, val_acc, dirpath):
    now = time.ctime()
    model.save_weights('../data/weights/{}'.format(now))
    save_model(model.to_json(), now, dirpath)
    save_config(model.get_config(), now, dirpath)
    save_result(starttime, batch_size, nb_epoch, conv_arch, dense, dropout,
                    X_shape, y_shape, train_acc, val_acc, dirpath)

def cnn_architecture(X_train, y_train, conv_arch=[(32,3),(64,3),(128,3)],
                    dense=[64,2], dropout=0.5, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=100, validation_split=0.2, patience=5, dirpath='../data/results/'):
    starttime = time.time()
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_shape = X_train.shape
    y_shape = y_train.shape
    describe(X_shape, y_shape, batch_size, dropout, nb_epoch, conv_arch, dense)

    # data augmentation:
    # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=validation_split)
    # datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    #                              rotation_range=10,
    #                              shear_range=0.2,
    #                              width_shift_range=0.2,
    #                              height_shift_range=0.2,
    #                              horizontal_flip=True)

    # datagen.fit(X_train)
    # model architecture:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(conv_arch[0][0], 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu',input_shape=(1, X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3])))

    if (conv_arch[0][1]-1) != 0:
        for i in range(conv_arch[0][1]-1):
            model.add(Convolution2D(conv_arch[0][0], 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    if conv_arch[1][1] != 0:
        for i in range(conv_arch[1][1]):
            model.add(Convolution2D(conv_arch[1][0], 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    if conv_arch[2][1] != 0:
        for i in range(conv_arch[2][1]):
            model.add(Convolution2D(conv_arch[2][0], 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())  # this converts 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
    if dense[1] != 0:
        for i in range(dense[1]):
            model.add(Dense(dense[0], activation='relu'))
            if dropout:
                model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    prediction = model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

    # optimizer:
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # set callback:
    callbacks = []
    if patience != 0:
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience, verbose=1)
        callbacks.append(early_stopping)

    print 'Training....'
    # fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
    # hist = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
    #                 samples_per_epoch=len(X_train), nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)

    '''without data augmentation'''
    hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size,
              validation_split=validation_split, callbacks=callbacks, shuffle=True, verbose=1)

    # model result:
    train_val_accuracy = hist.history
    train_acc = train_val_accuracy['acc']
    val_acc = train_val_accuracy['val_acc']
    print '          Done!'
    print '     Train acc: ', train_acc[-1]
    print 'Validation acc: ', val_acc[-1]
    print ' Overfit ratio: ', val_acc[-1]/train_acc[-1]

    logging(model, starttime, batch_size, nb_epoch, conv_arch, dense,
            dropout, X_shape, y_shape, train_acc, val_acc, dirpath)

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # import dataset:
    X_fname = '../data/X_train6_5pct.npy'
    y_fname = '../data/y_train6_5pct.npy'
    X_train = np.load(X_fname)
    y_train = np.load(y_fname)
    print 'Loading data...'

    cnn_architecture(X_train, y_train, conv_arch=[(32,3),(64,3),(128,3)], dense=[64,2], batch_size=256, nb_epoch=5, dirpath = '../data/results/')
```

Comment: Can you please add the Error

Comment: See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a Python 2 code

Comment: `print()` is a function in Python 3.5, and thus requires parenthesis. That's why Python's complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it was a small error. 
The CODE you copied is for Python2.x and you are running it on Python 3.x. You have ultimately two option

1. either use Python 2.x
2. Or port your Code from Python 2.x to 3.x using 2to3.py

P.S. Currently your error is  " Missing parentheses in call to 'print' "
so instead of `print ' X_train shape: ', X_shape` make it 
`print (' X_train shape: ', X_shape)` in every print statement.

Thanks